# DatePicker Icon hide after selection of Customer Type (ajax implemented Component) in Wicket framework

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, datepicker, wicket

I am creating UI using Wicket framework. When I click on Customer Registration, new page is load. and everything looks good. Date Picker icon is also there as shown in the picture.[image]

I implemented ajax on customer type. When I select Customer Type, Page must be rendered. And after rendering date picker icon is not there as shown in the picture.[image]

***HTML file:***

**File Header**

```
<head>
  <wicket:head>
    <script src="scripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $("#identityValue").mask("99999-9999999-9");
            $("#cnicBeneficial").mask("99999-9999999-9");
            $("#msisdn").mask("03999999999");
        });
    </script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery/customization.js">function();</script>

</wicket:head>
</head>
```

and 
**birthdate Field and div**

```
<div class="input" wicket:id="birthDateDiv">
<label for="birthDate"><wicket:message key="birthDate" /><span class="required">*</span></label> 
<input readonly="readonly" tabindex="6" type="text" size="10" wicket:id="birthDateField" id="birthDate" style="width: 150px;" />
</div>
```

***java Code:***

**Header:**

```
final String chooseDtTxt = this.basePage.getLocalizer().getString(
        "datepicker.chooseDate", basePage);

    add(new HeaderContributor(new IHeaderContributor() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        captcha = "";

        // localize the jquery datepicker based on users locale setting
        // locale specific js includes for datepicker are available at
        // http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/i18n/
        String localeLang = getLocale().getLanguage().toLowerCase();

        LOG.debug("Using DatePicker for locale language: {}",
            localeLang);

        response.renderJavascriptReference("scripts/jquery/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-en.js");
        response.renderJavascriptReference("scripts/jquery/jquery.min.js");
        response.renderJavascriptReference("scripts/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js");
        response.renderJavascriptReference("scripts/jquery/jquery.maskedinput.js");
        response.renderJavascriptReference("scripts/jquery/customization.js");

        RenderJavaScriptComponent renderJavaScriptComponent = new RenderJavaScriptComponent();
        renderJavaScriptComponent.renderDateComponent(response,
            "#birthDate", chooseDtTxt, true);
        renderJavaScriptComponent.renderDateComponent(response,
            "#cnicExpiryDate", chooseDtTxt, true, true);


        }
    }));
```

**BirthdateField and Div**

```
final WebMarkupContainer birthDateDiv = new WebMarkupContainer("birthDateDiv");

final DateTextField birthDateTextField = new DateTextField("birthDateField", new PropertyModel<Date>(
        this, "customer.birthDateString"), new PatternDateConverter(Constants.DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN_PARSE, false));
birthDateTextField.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

birthDateDiv.add(birthDateTextField);
birthDateDiv.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
form.add(birthDateDiv);
```

**and AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior is:**

```
customertypes.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

    if (customer.getCustomerTypeId() != null){
        kycDiv.setVisible(true);
        if(attachmentsPanel != null){
            attachmentsPanel.setVisible(true);  
        }

        permanentAddressDiv.setVisible(true);
        businessAddressDiv.setVisible(false);

        switch(customer.getCustomerTypeId().intValue()){
        case (Constants.MBANKING_CUSTOMER_TYPE):
                    kycDiv.setVisible(false);
        break;

        case (Constants.STANDARD_CONSUMER):
                    kycDiv.setVisible(false);
        break;

        case (Constants.MERCHANT): 
        break;

        case (Constants.MERCHANT_AGENT):
                    kycDiv.setVisible(false);
        break;

        case (Constants.BENEFICIARY): 
                    kycDiv.setVisible(false);
        break;

        case (Constants.MERCHANT_HEADQUARTER): 
                    accountProfileDiv.setVisible(false);
                    accountProfileMerchantDiv.setVisible(true);
        break;

        case (Constants.MERCHANT_DEALER):
                    kycDiv.setVisible(false);
        break;

        case (Constants.CONSUMER_WITH_FEE):
                    kycDiv.setVisible(false);
        break;

        case (Constants.CUSTOMER_TYPE_L1): 
        case (Constants.CUSTOMER_TYPE_L0): 
                    kycDiv.setVisible(false);
                    accountProfileDiv.setVisible(false);
                    accountProfileMerchantDiv.setVisible(false);
                    businessDetailDiv.setVisible(false);

                    motherNameDiv.setVisible(true);
                    fatherHusbandNameDiv.setVisible(true);
                    placeOfBirthDiv.setVisible(true);
                    mailingAddressDiv.setVisible(true);
                    msisdnDiv.setVisible(true);
                    kvInfoModeDiv.setVisible(true);
                    landLineDiv.setVisible(true);
                    kvIdentityTypeDiv.setVisible(true);
                    cnicExpiryDateDiv.setVisible(true);
                    kvIdentityValueDiv.setVisible(true);
                    birthDateTextField.setVisible(true);
                    birthDateDiv.setVisible(true);
                    identityInfoTitleDiv.setVisible(true);
                    rolesAndPrivilegesDiv.setVisible(false);

        break;

        case (Constants.CUSTOMER_TYPE_L2_INDIVIDUAL_NEW): 
        case (Constants.CUSTOMER_TYPE_L2_INDIVIDUAL_10000): 
        case (Constants.CUSTOMER_TYPE_L2_INDIVIDUAL_50000): 
        case (Constants.CUSTOMER_TYPE_L2_INDIVIDUAL_99999): 
        case (Constants.CUSTOMER_TYPE_L2_INDIVIDUAL_500000):

                    kycDiv.setVisible(true);
                    accountsDiv.setVisible(false);
                    businessDetailDiv.setVisible(false);
                    accountProfileDiv.setVisible(true);
                    accountProfileMerchantDiv.setVisible(false);
                    salaryDiv.setVisible(false);
                    otherIncomeDiv.setVisible(false);
                    typeOfTransactionDiv.setVisible(false);
                    currentBusinessSinceDiv.setVisible(false);
                    premisesDiv.setVisible(false);

                    motherNameDiv.setVisible(true);
                    fatherHusbandNameDiv.setVisible(true);
                    placeOfBirthDiv.setVisible(true);
                    mailingAddressDiv.setVisible(true);
                    msisdnDiv.setVisible(true);
                    kvInfoModeDiv.setVisible(true);
                    landLineDiv.setVisible(true);
                    kvIdentityTypeDiv.setVisible(true);
                    cnicExpiryDateDiv.setVisible(true);
                    kvIdentityValueDiv.setVisible(true);
                    birthDateTextField.setVisible(true);
                    birthDateDiv.setVisible(true);
                    identityInfoTitleDiv.setVisible(true);
                    rolesAndPrivilegesDiv.setVisible(false);

        break;
        case (Constants.CUSTOMER_TYPE_AGENT_FINJA): 
        case (Constants.CUSTOMER_TYPE_L2_MERCHANT): 
                    kycDiv.setVisible(true);
                    businessDetailDiv.setVisible(true);
                    permanentAddressDiv.setVisible(false);
                    accountProfileDiv.setVisible(false);
                    accountProfileMerchantDiv.setVisible(true);
                    salaryDiv.setVisible(true);
                    otherIncomeDiv.setVisible(true);
                    typeOfTransactionDiv.setVisible(true);
                    currentBusinessSinceDiv.setVisible(true);
                    premisesDiv.setVisible(true);
                    accountsDiv.setVisible(true);
                    typeOfCustomer_NotCustomerTypeDiv.setVisible(false);
                    purposeOfAccountDiv.setVisible(false);
                    bankRecognitionMediumDiv.setVisible(false);
                    modeOfTransactionDiv.setVisible(false);

                    motherNameDiv.setVisible(true);
                    fatherHusbandNameDiv.setVisible(true);
                    placeOfBirthDiv.setVisible(true);
                    mailingAddressDiv.setVisible(true);
                    msisdnDiv.setVisible(true);
                    kvInfoModeDiv.setVisible(true);
                    landLineDiv.setVisible(true);
                    kvIdentityTypeDiv.setVisible(true);
                    cnicExpiryDateDiv.setVisible(true);
                    kvIdentityValueDiv.setVisible(true);
                    birthDateTextField.setVisible(true);
                    birthDateDiv.setVisible(true);
                    identityInfoTitleDiv.setVisible(true);
                    rolesAndPrivilegesDiv.setVisible(false);
        break;

        case (Constants.CUSTOMER_TYPE_CST_SUB_AGENT): 
                    kycDiv.setVisible(false);
                    businessDetailDiv.setVisible(false);
                    businessAddressDiv.setVisible(false);
                    permanentAddressDiv.setVisible(false);
                    accountProfileDiv.setVisible(false);
                    accountProfileMerchantDiv.setVisible(false);
                    salaryDiv.setVisible(false);
                    otherIncomeDiv.setVisible(false);
                    typeOfTransactionDiv.setVisible(false);
                    currentBusinessSinceDiv.setVisible(false);
                    premisesDiv.setVisible(false);
                    accountsDiv.setVisible(false);
                    typeOfCustomer_NotCustomerTypeDiv.setVisible(false);
                    purposeOfAccountDiv.setVisible(false);
                    bankRecognitionMediumDiv.setVisible(false);
                    modeOfTransactionDiv.setVisible(false);

                    motherNameDiv.setVisible(false);
                    fatherHusbandNameDiv.setVisible(false);
                    placeOfBirthDiv.setVisible(false);
                    mailingAddressDiv.setVisible(false);
                    msisdnDiv.setVisible(false);
                    kvInfoModeDiv.setVisible(false);
                    landLineDiv.setVisible(false);
                    kvIdentityTypeDiv.setVisible(false);
                    cnicExpiryDateDiv.setVisible(false);
                    kvIdentityValueDiv.setVisible(false);
                    birthDateDiv.setVisible(false);
                    identityInfoTitleDiv.setVisible(false);
                    rolesAndPrivilegesDiv.setVisible(true);
        break;      

        case (Constants.CUSTOMER_TYPE_GUEST): 
                    kycDiv.setVisible(false);
                    attachmentsPanel.setVisible(false);
        break;

        default : 
        break;
        }

    }else{
    }

    target.addComponent(kycDiv);
    target.addComponent(accountProfileDiv);
    target.addComponent(accountProfileMerchantDiv);

    target.addComponent(businessDetailDiv);
    target.addComponent(permanentAddressDiv);

    target.addComponent(businessNameDiv);
    target.addComponent(ntnNumberDiv);
    target.addComponent(businessAddressDiv);

    target.addComponent(salaryDiv);
    target.addComponent(otherIncomeDiv);
    target.addComponent(typeOfTransactionDiv);
    target.addComponent(currentBusinessSinceDiv);
    target.addComponent(premisesDiv);

    target.addComponent(monthlyExpectedDepositDiv);
    target.addComponent(monthlyExpectedWithdrawalDiv);
    target.addComponent(expectedAvgBalanceDiv);
    target.addComponent(annualTurnoverDiv);
    target.addComponent(expectedMonthlyCreditSalesDiv);

    target.addComponent(averageMonthlyInflowDiv);
    target.addComponent(averageMonthlyOutflowDiv);
    target.addComponent(averageYearlySalesDiv);
    target.addComponent(avergaeYearlyIncomeDiv);

    target.addComponent(typeOfCustomer_NotCustomerTypeDiv);
    target.addComponent(purposeOfAccountDiv);
    target.addComponent(bankRecognitionMediumDiv);
    target.addComponent(modeOfTransactionDiv);

    target.addComponent(infoModeSMSEmail);
    target.addComponent(motherNameDiv);
    target.addComponent(fatherHusbandNameDiv);
    target.addComponent(placeOfBirthDiv);

    target.addComponent(msisdnDiv);
    target.addComponent(kvInfoModeDiv);
    target.addComponent(landLineDiv);
    target.addComponent(kvIdentityTypeDiv);
    target.addComponent(cnicExpiryDateDiv);
    target.addComponent(kvIdentityValueDiv);
    target.addComponent(birthDateTextField);
    target.addComponent(birthDateDiv);
    target.addComponent(mailingAddressDiv);
    target.addComponent(identityInfoTitleDiv);


    if(attachmentsPanel != null){
        target.addComponent(attachmentsPanel);  
    }

    }
});
```

Full code(html and java) files also uploaded on this link 
http://pastebin.com/Dr92A9Vq

Answer (score 0):

Your AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior adds the "birthDate" component to the `AjaxRequestTarget`, thus replacing its markup in the browser.

This reverts whatever the following line has done:

```
renderJavaScriptComponent.renderDateComponent(response, "#birthDate", chooseDtTxt, true);
```

Your options are:

- make your dateField a 'real' component, i.e. let it take care of adding the necessary JavaScript
- update the whole panel when the customer type changes, so that the header contributions are restored after an Ajax update:

  target.add(RegisterCustomerPanel.this);

Update: Why isn't dateField a 'real' component?

Because it isn't self contained. When you update it via Ajax, it should still function. It doesn't, because it is dependent on the containing panel to provide the JavaScript.

Comment: datefield is a real  component,datefield just get calender from javascript file. and if I wanna update whole panel how I can do this? Can you elaborate two points with example please?

Comment: I've expanded my answer.

Comment: In my case, I will add  **target.addComponent(form);** because main div wicket id is **registerCustomerForm** and mapping of this div in java is **final Form<?> form = new Form("registerCustomerForm",
  new CompoundPropertyModel<RegisterCustomerPanel>(this));**   am I right?

Comment: If the form is contributing the JavaScript part, then yes, you can just update the whole form. Note that if you add your header contributor to the containing panel, updating the form won't help.